# UIView 内にContainerViewを作成しStoryboardのUIViewControllerを入れたい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

Xcode 7.3、Swift2の環境で、
[[iOS swift] ContainerViewをプログラムで作りたい](http://www.kuma-de.com/blog/2016-04-25/7174)
こちらのページを参考にして、

UIViewをコードでContainerViewにして、
StoryBoardのUIViewを入れようとしたのですが、
下記コード内の「 <=ココ」の部分で、

> Could not cast value of type 'Test.StartViewController' (0x1000db240) to 'Test.TestViewController' (0x1000db088).

というエラーが出ます。

いろいろ調べてみたのですが、ContainerViewをコードで作成する情報は、
日本語ではあまり見当たらず、原因がわかりませんでした。

どこが問題なのか、ご教示いただけたらと思います。
どうか、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import UIKit

class StartViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!

var printViewController:TestViewController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Hello Container"

    printViewController = createHorizontalViewController("Top")
    displayContentController(printViewController!, container: swipeView)

}


func createHorizontalViewController(containerTitle:String)->TestViewController{
    let sb:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let hController:TestViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! TestViewController // <=ココ
    // hController.containerTitle = containerTitle
    return hController
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func displayContentController(content:UIViewController, container:UIView){
    addChildViewController(content)
    content.view.frame = container.bounds
    container.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func hideContentController(content:UIViewController){
    content.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    content.view.removeFromSuperview()
    content.removeFromParentViewController()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたのコードのこの部分、

```
sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

これは、「初期ViewControllerをインスタンス化しろ」と言うメソッドです。あなたのアプリでは初期ViewControllerとして、`StartViewController`を指定しているようですので、そのインスタンス(その時走っている`StartViewController`と同クラスだが別のインスタンス)が作成されてしまいます。それをキャストで別のViewControllerに変換することはできません。

`TestViewController`のインスタンスをstoryboardに追加(すでに存在するならその属性を修正)し、**Class**を`TestViewController`にした上で、**Storyboard ID**を正しく設定してください。(以下では、Storyboard IDとしてTestViewControllerを指定したものとして記述しますが、クラス名とStoryboard IDを同じにする必要はありません。)

`TestViewController`をインスタンス化するコードはこんな風にしないといけません。

```
    let hController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewController") as! TestViewController
```

(文字列の、`"TestViewController"`の部分をStoryboard IDで設定した内容に合わせます。)

ご質問タイトルにある「ContainerViewを作成し」の部分がうまくいくかどうかは、全く試せていませんので、上記の修正でうまくいかない部分が残っている場合は、ご質問内容を編集して必要な情報を追記するなどした上で、コメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にした記事のサンプルプログラムを見ると、StoryboardをViewControllerごとに分割していて、StoryboardごとにInitial View Controllerを設定してありました。そのとおりに、Storyboardを分割すると、『sb.instantiateInitialViewController()』でContainerすることができました。Storyboardを分割しない方法では、いろいろ試してみましたが、私の知識・技術不足で、結局できませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: あなたのコード+上の回答の修正で問題なくcontainerとして表示することができましたので、知識・技術不足と言うよりもちょっとした勘違い程度の見落としだろうかと思います。私が引っかかったところと言うと元記事の「ContainerViewは使わずにUIViewを使う」あたりでしょうか。時間が取れましたら再度おためしください。